# Insert sorted linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Trying to write a function that asks the user to input an integer, then inserts it to the linked list in ascending order.

```
typedef struct _listnode{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;         

typedef struct _linkedlist{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;           

void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l)
{
    ListNode *cur;
    int x;
    printf("please input an integer you want to add to the linked list:");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if (l->head == NULL) // linkedlist is empty, inserting as first element
    {
        l->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        l->head->item = x;
        l->head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cur = l->head;
        if (x < cur->item) // data is smaller than first element, we will insert at first element and update head.
        {
            cur->next->item = cur->item; // store current element as next element.
            cur->item = x;
            cur->next = cur->next->next;
        }
    }
    l->size++;
}
```

The function is not completed yet, but why is my code not working if the data is smaller than the first element?

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore are basically reserved for 'the implementation' to use (it is marginally more nuanced than that, but only marginally so).  Avoid using such names yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create node for the new element, like this:

```
ListNode* newNode =  malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
newNode ->item = x;
```

Now change your code:

```
if (x < l->head->item) // data is smaller than first element, we will insert at first element and update head.
    {
        newNode->next = l->head;
        l->head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Like you said the code is not complete yes and loop via the list till you find the right place to insert the new node.

Can write 1 code to handle all cases.
One common way to handle those cases is to do that is to have node in the head ofthe link list.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` branch of your insertion function assumes that `cur->next` is not `NULL` (because you set a value to `cur->next->item`). Now imagine inserting two numbers (the second smaller than the first). In the first insertion, `l->head->next` is set to `NULL`. Thus, in the second insertion, the program will crash on trying to set `cur->next->item` to some value. You should create a node (i.e., allocate memory via `malloc()`), initialize the node to contain fields as desired, and then set it as `cur->next`.